# c# remove string with quotes from string

Tags: c#, string, url, xml-namespaces

I have a string, containing XML namespace, and I cant seem to remove this part

```
xmlns="http://www.rar.org/xyz/"
```

I've tried

```
return textWriter.ToString().Replace(@"xmlns="http://www.rar.org/xyz/"", "");
```

but this does not compile.

Comment: What is the `textWriter` variable? If it is a `TextWriter` instance, then `ToString` isn't doing what you think that it is. It will return the name of the class, not the text, as it is inherited from the `Object` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the string.  Since you are providing a verbatim string literal (by using the @), you need to use two quotes to escape it:

```
return textWriter.ToString().Replace(@"xmlns=""http://www.rar.org/xyz/""", "");
```